# How to prevent user to add control on specific location?

Tags: c#, user-controls

Previously I have posted a question about [How to create non-client area?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22267736/3391751) and I got my answer. Now, I want to prevent user to add control on specific client area.So, User can add control only on allocated portion of client area.

The control should be looked like this.
[image]

**CLASS DESIGN & CODES**

[**XWizardControl:**](http://dantainfosoft.a78.org/Code/XWizardControl.txt) is the main user control which will be placed on form.

[**XWizardPageWindow:**](http://dantainfosoft.a78.org/Code/XWizardPageWindow.txt) is the container which will contains all `XWizardPages`. This control will be placed on the `XWizardControl`. User will add pages from the Control Collection Dialog Window.

[**XWizardPageCollection:**](http://dantainfosoft.a78.org/Code/XWizardPageCollection.txt) is the collection of `XWizardPage`.

[**XWizardPage:**](http://dantainfosoft.a78.org/Code/XWizardPage.txt) user will place other controls here.

[**XWizardPageDesigner:**](http://dantainfosoft.a78.org/Code/XWizardPageDesigner.txt) Control designer for `XWizardPage` control

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the *nonclient rectangle* incorrectly.

> "On entry, the structure contains the proposed window rectangle for the window. On exit, the structure should contain the screen coordinates of the corresponding window client area." -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-

Also notice that the `RECT` structure is a `ltrb` rectangle and not a `xywh` rectangle.

**Incorrect**

You shouldn't set the values explicit:

```
ncRect.top = 68; //<----
ncRect.left = 176; //<----
ncRect.bottom -= 68;

ncParams.rectProposed.top = 68; //<----
ncParams.rectProposed.left = 176; //<----
ncParams.rectProposed.bottom -= 68;
```

**Correct**

But rather add (`+=`) or subtract (`-=`) to/from the rectangle:

```
ncRect.top += 30; //<---- 30px top-margin
ncRect.left += 50; //<---- 50px left-margin
ncRect.bottom -= 20; //<---- 20px bottom-margin

ncParams.rectProposed.top += 30;
ncParams.rectProposed.left += 50;
ncParams.rectProposed.bottom -= 20;
```

**Note**

If you don't paint the nonclient area correctly, and a control is placed at lets say the location `-5, -5`, then the control may appear as if it's *inside* the nonclient area.