# ControlCollection items could not be saved

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controlcollection

I have created a control with controlcollection. When I add items from the property window at design time. It added perfectly. Also when I open it back. Added items shows me. But, When I close the form then open it again the items was removed.

**Now I have added two Items in the collection.**
The items was looking perfectly.
[image]

But, When I open the `Form.Desigern.cs` file the following line is missing.

```
this.xWizardControl.Window.Controls.Add(this.xWizardPage1);
this.xWizardControl.Window.Controls.Add(this.xWizardPage2);
```

[image]

The code is looks like this.

```
public class XWizardPageWindow : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl, ISupportInitialize
{
    private XWizardPageCollection _pages;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public XWizardPageCollection Pages
    {
        get { return _pages; }
        set { _pages = value; }
    }
    public XWizardPageWindow()
    {
    }
    #region Override Methods
    protected override ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
    {
        if (_pages == null)
            _pages = new XWizardPageCollection(this);
        return _pages;
    }
    #endregion


    #region ISupportInitialize Members

    public void BeginInit()
    {
        //DO NOTHING
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        //DO NOTHING
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**ControlCollection Class**

```
public class XWizardPageCollection : System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection
{
    public delegate void XWizardPageEventHandler(object sender, XWizardPageEventArgs e);
    List<XWizardPage> _pages = new List<XWizardPage>();
    #region Constructor
    public XWizardPageCollection(System.Windows.Forms.Control owner): base(owner)
    {}
    #endregion

    #region Override Methods
    public override void Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control value)
    {
        base.Add(value);
        value.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        ((XWizardPage)value).BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.NoBorder;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Destructor
    ~XWizardPageCollection()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: May I answer in `vb.net`?

Comment: Sure, I can understand both languages.

Comment: How do you add the control to the collection? Using the shown control collection dialog? You see, I couldn't reproduce this behavior. However, you could try to change the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute` from `Visible` to `Content`. If no success, I have some recommendations. First, one should never change the `ControlCollection` after it's first created. So the `Pages` property should be decleared `ReadOnly`. With that being said, if you want to do this as the `TabControl` does it, then `Pages` property should be a wrapped list reflecting the controls collection.

Comment: Yes, the controls will be added from the control collection dialog shown in the screen shot. `XWizardPageWindow` will contains `XWizardPages` class object and `XWizardPageWindow` will be added on `XWizardControl` client area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one should never change the [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) once created and returned by [CreateControlsInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrolsinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So the `Pages` property should be defined as `ReadOnly`.

Secondly, when using [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you're telling the code generator to create a new instance of `Pages`, which we don't want.  So change the [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `Visible` to `Content` and the code generator will produce code for the contents of the object (Pages), rather than for the object itself.